# clickhouse cluster : data not replicated

Tags: replication, database-replication, clickhouse

I have a cluster with 2 nodes for a test.
1 Shard and 2 replica.
3 nodes in the zookeeper cluster

```
<remote_servers>
  <ch_cluster>
    <shard>
      <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
      <replica>
        <host>ch1</host>
        <port>9000</port>
      </replica>
      <replica>
        <host>ch2</host>
        <port>9000</port>
      </replica>
    </shard>
  </ch_cluster>
</remote_servers>
```

macros in ch1 :

```
  <macros>
        <shard>shard_01</shard>
        <replica>replica-01</replica>
    </macros>
```

macro in ch2 :

```
   <macros>
        <shard>shard_01</shard>
        <replica>replica-02</replica>
    </macros>
```

zookeeper configuration :

```
   <zookeeper>
        <node>
            <host>zoo1</host>
            <port>2181</port>
        </node>
        <node>
            <host>zoo2</host>
            <port>2181</port>
        </node>
        <node>
            <host>zoo3</host>
            <port>2181</port>
        </node>
    </zookeeper>
```

I create the first table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.hits_local ON CLUSTER ch_cluster
(
  `date` Datetime,
  `user_id` String,
  `pageviews` Int32
)
ENGINE = ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/ch_cluster/tables/{shard}/hits_local', '{replica}')
PARTITION BY toStartOfHour(date)
ORDER BY (date)
```

then i create a distributed table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.hits ON CLUSTER 'ch_cluster'
AS test.hits_local 
 (
      `date` Datetime,
      `user_id` String,
      `pageviews` Int32
    )
ENGINE = Distributed('ch_cluster', 'test', 'hits_local')
```

then i insert data in **test.hits_local** table in **ch1**
when select data from **test.hits_local** in **ch2** there is no data

then i tried to select from **test.hits** Distributed table in **ch2** the data appear after **5-6 min**
but no data in **test.hits_local** in **ch2**

my question when the data replicated to **ch2**?
who is responsible to replicate data to another node ? is it a zookeeper or should i insert the data into tables in ch1 and ch2?
should i change <**internal_replication**>*true*</**internal_replication**> to **false** ?

is it necessary for the data to be replicated to test.hits_local in **ch2**?

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should i change <internal_replication>true</internal_replication> to false ?

No, you should not. If you use ReplicatedMergeTree internal_replication **MUST BE true**.

Replication is done by ReplicatedMergeTree table engine internally.

Replicas communicate using their hostnames and port=9009.
Check system.replication_queue table for errors.

Most probably the node "ch1" announced own hostname in Zookeeper i.e. "localhost".
So the second node  "ch2" unable to access localhost:9009 or something.
Such issues you can find in clickhouse-server.log or system.replication_queue (it has a column with errors).

Usually replication lag is less than 2 seconds even in very high-loaded setups.

Comment: zookeeper runs on separate nodes.
I checked the log file if found this error:  -
<Error> default.hits_local (ReplicatedMergeTreeRestartingThread ): 
Couldn't start replication: Replica /clickhouse/ch_cluster/tables/01/hits_local/replicas/replica-1 
appears to be already active (host: ch-01.localdomain, port: 9009, tcp_port: 9000, database: default, table: hits_local, scheme: http, ). 
If you're sure it's not, try again in a minute or remove znode /clickhouse/ch_cluster/tables/01/hits_local/replicas/replica-1/is_active manually. 
@Denny Crane

Comment: @alim it signals about misconfiguration. Check that NS ch-01.localdomain is available from all hosts

Comment: Thank you so much Denny Crane :)
it was ch1 then I change it to ch-01